# Python Function returning string with quotes

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a function and returning three values, The return value for my function is

```
(1, 3, "<class 'int'>")
```

while I want to return

```
(1, 3, <class 'int'>)
```

How do I remove the quotes from my `return value.str(type(element))` is the value which is returning the 3rd value

```
def is_list_permutation(L1, L2):
    L1set = set(L1)
    L2set = set(L2)
    count = 0
    element = ''
    if L1 == [] and L2 == []:
        return(None,None,None)    
    elif len(L1) == len(L2) and L1set == L2set:
       for a in L1:
          if L1.count(a) == L2.count(a):
              if L1.count(a) > count:
                  count = L1.count(a)
                  element = a
                  return(element,count,str(type(element)))
          else:
              return False
              break

    else:
       return False
```

so if i give

```
L1 = [1, 'b', 1, 'c', 'c', 1]
L2 = ['c', 1, 'b', 1, 1, 'c']
```

then the result is `(1, 3, "<class 'int'>")` while I want `(1, 3, <class 'int'>)`

Comment: Please post the code of the function you want to change

Comment: How do i remove quotes while printing this value "<class 'str'>" which is a result of str(type(char))

Comment: Just FYI, it is usually a good idea to keep return values consistent, especially with tuples, in the sense that you return tuples of the same length and respective types.

Comment: Just remove the str:  return(element,count,type(element))

Answer (score 2):

Your function is returning a tuple with three elements: `element`, `count` and the string representation of the type of `element`. At no point, this has any string representation which you’re seeing there. You just get back a tuple.

Now, when you *print* that tuple, then the print function will actually try to convert it into a string. For a tuple, this string representation is defined to be a set of parentheses `()`, and the `repr()` string representation of each tuple element inside.

For numbers, this will look fine since `repr(5)` happens to be the string `'5'`. But for strings, the repr will add quotes to make sure that the return string would be valid Python code:

```
>>> repr('foo')
"'foo'"
>>> print(repr('foo'))
'foo'
```

Now, when you say, you want the result without those quotes, you have to think about what that actually means. You could easily format the result string yourself. For example like this:

```
return '({0}, {1}, {2})'.format(element, count, str(type(element)))
```

This will return *a string* that would look like the way you want.

However, by doing that, you also lose the information you had when you returned a tuple. Now, you just return a string that has no information about the actual source values. So you cannot take the `count` value out without parsing the string again.

So, think about what you want to do: Do you actually just want something nice to print, or do you actually want to get those three values individually as a return value to be able to use them for something else afterwards?

You could always consider printing the text in the desired format later, if you already have the return values as a tuple…

---

Btw.: Note that when not calling `str(type(element))` but just `type(element)`, you would get back a type element (instead of a string). And the `repr()` of a type element happens to be exactly what you would want to have. So as a quick fix, you could always get rid of that `str()` call there.

Comment: thanks for the help Poke. I have this specific requirement that I have to print it in this way. Your Format option is giving me the output in "(c, 3, <class 'str'>)"  format where as I want  (c, 3, <class 'str'>), without the quotes

Comment: @nems *Again*, this is *a string* you get back. What you are looking at though is the `repr()` of that string. Try printing it using `print()` and you will see that there are no actual quotes.

Answer (score 1):

***There will always be some quotes around it because it is a string!***

If you want to return `None` when the string is `""` then you could do this:

```
x = str(type(s))
return(element, count, x if x else None)
```

Comment: str(type(element))  actually returns "<class 'int'>"  but i want to return <class 'int'> without quotes

Comment: s ='abc'  and i do str(type(s)) it displays "<class 'str'>"  , while I want the sameoutput I dont want the double quotes

Comment: Clean up your answer. If there's incorrect information, it's better not to let other readers see it.

Comment: Thanks @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ.